# add class making scroll with mouse and browser using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi please i need some help on a issue, i have a fixed menu that goes fixed when capturing the coordinates, and when the menu puts sticky when i make scroll with the mouse or directly on the browser, i want to add a class, but if a make click on the menu i want to remove that class, this its my code:

```
$(document).on('scroll', Amargin);

function Amargin(e) {

  if ($('nav').hasClass('fixed_menu')) {
    $('main').addClass('margin');
  }
  else
  {
    $('main').removeClass('margin');
  }

  e.preventDefault();
}
```

Also im adding to the tag nav a class that calls fixed_menu, that makes the menu with the position fixed, that its why im using the if sentence, because i only want to add the class margin when the class fixed_menu appears, and when i make scroll with the mouse or browser, but when i make click on the menu i want to remove it, keep in mind that when i click on the sticky menu it moves capturing the scrollTop and offset.Top event, making a animate page.

Comment: Aside from the fact that I'd move your preventDefault(), and possibly stopImmediatePropagation depending on your jQuery version, can you describe the results you're getting from your current code?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a cool idea, so I thought I would take a shot at it. I think you are looking for something like [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/maxrbaldwin/6FmUQ/1/).

Your logic is off. The basic idea is that if you have a navigation bar at the top  you want a new navigation bar to appear and stick to the top of the screen when a user scrolls past the bar at the top. Therefore you need to check to see if the user's position from the top of the document is greater than the height of the navigation bar.

```
var top = $('body').scrollTop();
var navHeight = $('#navBar').height();

if(top > navHeight) {
    $('#fixedBar').fadeIn();
} else {
    $('#fixedBar').fadeOut();
}
```

I could make this more dynamic so that there is no need for a second navigation bar, but for this example I believe that this approach works.

Comment: Thanks for your help but this its not what i asked.

Comment: @rob286 the general idea is correct right? Our approaches are kinda different?